# pairwise(1 to 1) multiplication of columns to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as such:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3.... Col64   Col1 Volume Col2 Volume....Col64 Volume.... Col1 Value Col2 Value...Col 64 Value

 2     3   4         5        5           7             9                 3         5
 3     4   5         11       8           6             5                 6         5
 5     3   4         6       10          11             5                 3         4
```

I want to multiply Col1 with Col1 Volume and then divide by Col1 Value and place the value in a new column called 'Col1 result'

similarly multiply Col2 with Col2 Volume and then divide by Col2 Value and place the value in a new column called 'Col2 result'

I wish to do this for every row of those columns.

Output should be as such and these columns should be appended to the existing dataframe.

```
Col1 Result  Col2 Result
3.33         4.2
6            4.8
16.6         8.25
...
```

How can I perform this operation? It also has to be 1 to 1 multiplication, that is only the first row of Col1  should be multiplied with Col1 Volume and divided by first row of Col1 Value.

Doing it manually would take a lot of time.

Comment: kindly provide a minimal reproducible example, with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for get all columns with `Volume` and `Value` with `$` for end of string, remove substrings and then filter `df` by columns from `df1`, multiple and divide columns with [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html), replace missing columns `0` and append to original DataFrame:

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='Volume$').rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(' Volume',''))
df2 = df.filter(regex='Value$').rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(' Value',''))

df = df.join(df[df1.columns].mul(df1).div(df2).add_suffix(' Result').fillna(0))
print (df)
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col64  Col1 Volume  Col2 Volume  Col64 Volume  \
0     2     3     4      5            5            7             9   
1     3     4     5     11            8            6             5   

   Col1 Value  Col2 Value  Col64 Value  Col1 Result  Col2 Result  Col64 Result  
0           3           5            7     3.333333          4.2      6.428571  
1           6           5            7     4.000000          4.8      7.857143
```

Comment: this is resulting in the result columns being filled with nan, I have other columns apart from Col1, Col2, such as year and id. maybe this is the problem?. also do columns need to sorted alphabetically to give correct results? my dataframe is not sorted alphabetical column wise(not alphabetically sorted horizontally)

Comment: @Jahrakal - Can you check `print (df1.columns)` and `print (df2.columns)` ? Are columns in both same `Col1` to `Col64`  ?

Comment: yes they are the same, but the order of the columns is different. will this affect the results? will the correct columns be multiplied or will it be multiplied based on the order?

Comment: @Jahrakal - It is weird, for me working well. Are data confidental?

Comment: no it is not confidential

Comment: @Jahrakal - Can you send me data to my emial from my profile?

Comment: can you send me your email?

Comment: @Jahrakal - run code in my profile for email, please

Comment: hello, i have shared the data to you.

Comment: @Jahrakal - tested  and find some columns missing - it is reason for NaN columns